# Why can't we have 2D UIImage Arrays?

Tags: arrays, swift, image, multidimensional-array, uiimage

```
var string2DArray = [[String]]()
var bool2DArray = [[Bool]]()
var int2DArray = [[Int]]()
var image2DArray = [[UIImage]]()

string2DArray[0][0].append("Test String")
bool2DArray[0][0].append(true)
int2DArray[0][0].append(20)

image2DArray[0][0].append(TestImage)
```

All the 2D arrays works as follows. But I fail to add any image to the 2D UIImage array. Is this the correct way to declare or use it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: image2DArray[0].append(TestImage) try this

Answer (score 0):

No that's not how you use a 2D array. Your arrays are completely empty, so they don't have an element at index `0`, so accessing `[0]` would not work.

To add something to index `[0][0]`, you need to append an array with just one element:

```
image2DArray.append([yourImage])
```

If you would like an array where you can just set the values like this:

```
image2DArray[3][4] = ...
```

You can initialise an array with everything being `nil` first:

```
var image2DArray: [[UIImage?]] = 
    Array(repeating: Array(repeating: nil, count: secondDimensionCount), count: firstDimensionCount)
```